# How to prevent a TextBlock with TextTrimming CharacterEllipsis to extend Column with Width Auto

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hello World" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hello ABC DEF World" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This results in the following User Interface:

[image]

I would like the TextBlock "Hello ABC DEF World" to trim and not extend the column width.

To have this result:

[image]

**Edit:**

Want to point out

- I wouldn't need it to be a `Grid` it could be any content control (`StackPanel`, `DockPanl`, `Canvas` and so on)
- I wouldn't need it to be a `TextBlock` it could be any control (`Run`, `Label` and so on)

If what I desire is possible with a different combination of controls, I am more than willing to give it a try.

What I want in non-code terms:

- I want 2 lines of text, the first line of text is the "main" information, and the second line of text is the "minor" information.
- The "main" information should stretch fully to show its full text.
- The "minor" information should only stretch as far as the main goes and not more, if it is longer it should Trim

I know I could achieve this goal with the following XAML:

```
<TextBlock ...
           x:Name="MainInfo" />
<TextBlock ...
           MaxWidth="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=MainInfo}" />
```

But if possible I would like to avoid the `Binding` on `ActualWidth`.

I hoped that `HorizontalAlignment = Left;` would prevent the `TextBlock`'s desire to stretch, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: That are contradicting requirements. Auto means auto. Set a fixed width instead.

Comment: @Clemens - but I wouldn’t know the width to set, as the text is dynamically, the second textblock is a secondary text that has less meaning and shouldn’t widen the column - any recommendations are welcome

Comment: @Clemens - you may want to look at the edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if possible I would like to not use the Binding on ActualWidth.

Well, you need to define the width contraint somehow. `Auto` effectively means that the column will grow along with the widest element in it, i.e. the "minor" information `TextBlock` in this case.

So you should set the `Width` of the column to the `ActualWidth` of `MainInfo`, for example using a binding. Or programmatically. Either way, you have to set it one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in multiple ways.

Depends on the exact desired purpose.

One notable and easy example would be to use some trickery

You could put the main textblock and a rectangle in a horizontally aligned stackpanel with a row span of 2 and with a higher Z index than the secondary textblock. You set the rectangle to have the height equal with the sum of the two textblocks and the width must be set by you after your desired specifications. The two textblocks must have set a fixed height, and the textblock that is inside the stackpanel with the rectangle must be aligned to the top vertically inside the stackpanel. The result, if implemented correctly, should be a rectangle that is covering the part of the secondary textblock that is making the secondary textblock bigger than the main textblock.